# Facebook share button suddenly got disappeared from product page in magento

Tags: facebook, magento

I am developing a `magento` site and I implemented the `social share extension`. But after some time the `facebook` share button got disappeared from the product page. The share button used to come along side the facebook like button. Please suggest how can I bring back the button as this button is coming in the share button dropdown but I need it seperately along side the facebook share button.
I am attaching a screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: can you please check in private window mode? i hope you can see there.

Comment: I have checked there as well but with no luck.

Comment: can you see any errors on console toolbar?

Comment: I can't see any error on my console bar.